# How to setState, object value in the stateless component in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

I am using a stateless component and got value from the API with Axios & useEffect(), then I have set one value in the state but I want to set response object in the state:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Login(props) {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

function validateForm() {
    return email.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
}

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'api/users')
        .then(response =>{
            // how to set my value: response.data.data
            setUserData(response.data.data);
            console.log(response.data.data);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
},[])
```

Comment: Please update your code with this lines: 

const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
setUserData(response.data.data);

Comment: uncomment your line `const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});` and you can update it your state like:  `setUserData(response.data.data);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setUserData` is a function to update your `userData` value. The code below should do the trick

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

 useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'api/users')
        .then(response =>{
            // how to set my value: response.data.data
            setUserData(response.data.data)
            console.log(response.data.data)
        }, error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
},[])
```

Comment: Then access your data using `userData` variable